# Can't use string ("XXX") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl

This is the log I am trying to parse:

```
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/startup_ptf_pats.sh startup initiated by waljoh @ Tue Nov  1      06:27:54 EDT 2011
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/startup_ptf_pats.sh verifying that engine is change controlled
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_change_controlled_files.sh all change controlled commands files are in synch
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_today_is_holiday.sh Today is NOT a holiday
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_ntpq.sh 159.79.35.42 time offset (0) is below 100
```

This is the script  I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $todays_date = `/bin/date +%m-%d-%y`;
chomp $todays_date ;

my $grabDIR = "/data/noc/startup/logs/";
my $grabFILE = "pats." . "$todays_date" . ".txt";

print "$grabDIR$grabFILE\n" ;

my FILE;
open (FILE, "more $grabDIR$grabFILE | ");
while (<FILE>) {
        my $line = $_;
        print $line
        sleep 1;
}
```

This is the error:

> /data/noc/startup/logs/pats.11-01-11.txt
>   Can't use string ("06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/start") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at ./log_grap line 17,  line 1.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the print statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a semicolon:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    print $line; # semicolon!
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to get the date?

Comment: Is there a better way to open up the file - should I be using the more with a pipe

Comment: Please ask those as separate questions.